How to see personal records of 100m, 400m and 800m on garmin connect?
On the personal records of my garmin connect I can see 1k, 5k, 1mile etc, but I don't know how to see my fastest 100 metres or 400 metres or 800meters. Is there an extension or other app or fitness device that captures these?

The only distances Garmin currently supports for Running are:

1 km
1 mi
5K
10K
Half Marathon
Marathon Longest
Run

You can create a free account on Strava and set your garmin app to automatically export all of your data to Strava (Settings, Connected Apps).  In Strava, you can see your 'Best Efforts' for these distances:

400m
1/2 mile
1K
1 mile
2 mile
5K
10K
15K
10 mile
20K
Half-Marathon
30K
Marathon

1/2 mile is about 805 meters and it doesn't have 100m, but that gets you close to what you're looking for.
